# CreateTexture2D and CreateDepthStencilView failing

Tags: winapi, directx-11

I am trying to learn Directx 11.0. I have encountered an error. This is the code.

```
// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header files
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>

// include the Direct3D Library file
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

// define the screen resolution
#define SCREEN_WIDTH  800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

// global declarations
IDXGISwapChain *swapchain = NULL;             // the pointer to the swap chain interface
ID3D11Device *dev = NULL;                     // the pointer to our Direct3D device interface
ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon = NULL;           // the pointer to our Direct3D device context
ID3D11RenderTargetView *backbuffer = NULL;    // the pointer to our back buffer
ID3D11InputLayout *pLayout = NULL;            // the pointer to the input layout
ID3D11VertexShader *pVS = NULL;               // the pointer to the vertex shader
ID3D11PixelShader *pPS = NULL;                // the pointer to the pixel shader
ID3D11Buffer *pVBuffer = NULL;                // the pointer to the vertex buffer
ID3D11Buffer *pIBuffer = NULL;                // the pointer to the index buffer
ID3D11DepthStencilView *pDView = NULL;        // the pointer to depth stencil view
ID3D11Texture2D *pDStencil = NULL;            // the pointer to depth stencil

// a struct to define a single vertex
struct VERTEX{FLOAT X, Y, Z; D3DXCOLOR Color;};

// function prototypes
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void RenderFrame(void);     // renders a single frame
void CleanD3D(void);        // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void InitGraphics(void);    // creates the shape to render
void InitPipeline(void);    // loads and prepares the shaders

// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                   int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    RECT wr = {0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT};
    AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                          "WindowClass",
                          "Our First Direct3D Program",
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          wr.right - wr.left,
                          wr.bottom - wr.top,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    InitD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while(TRUE)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }

        RenderFrame();
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    CleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(message)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc (hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}


// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

    // clear out the struct for use
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    // fill the swap chain description struct
    scd.BufferCount = 1;                                   // one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;    // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferDesc.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;                   // set the back buffer width
    scd.BufferDesc.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;                 // set the back buffer height
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;     // how swap chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                               // the window to be used
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 4;                              // how many multisamples
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;                                   // windowed/full-screen mode
    scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;    // allow full-screen switching

    // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct
    D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
                                  D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
                                  NULL,
                                  D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG,
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
                                  &scd,
                                  &swapchain,
                                  &dev,
                                  NULL,
                                  &devcon);


    // get the address of the back buffer
    ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

    // use the back buffer address to create the render target
    dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backbuffer);
    pBackBuffer->Release();

    //Create depth stencil buffer
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
    descDepth.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    descDepth.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
    descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
    descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = 4;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
    descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;

    dev->CreateTexture2D( &descDepth, NULL, &pDStencil );

    // Create the depth stencil view
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC descDSV;
    descDSV.Format = descDepth.Format;
    descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
    descDSV.Texture2DMS.UnusedField_NothingToDefine = 0;

    dev->CreateDepthStencilView( pDStencil, &descDSV, &pDView );

    // set the render target as the back buffer
    devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer, pDView);

    // Set the viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    viewport.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    InitPipeline();
    InitGraphics();
}


// this is the function used to render a single frame
void RenderFrame(void)
{
    // clear the back buffer to a deep blue
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

    //clear the depth stencil view
    devcon->ClearDepthStencilView(pDView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH|D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

        // select which vertex buffer to display
        UINT stride = sizeof(VERTEX);
        UINT offset = 0;
        devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pVBuffer, &stride, &offset);

        //set index buffer
        devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(pIBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);

        // select which primtive type we are using
        devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

        // draw the vertex buffer to the back buffer
        devcon->DrawIndexed(9, 0, 0);

    // switch the back buffer and the front buffer
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
}


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void CleanD3D(void)
{
    swapchain->SetFullscreenState(FALSE, NULL);    // switch to windowed mode

    // close and release all existing COM objects
    if(pLayout)pLayout->Release();
    if(pVS)pVS->Release();
    if(pPS)pPS->Release();
    if(pVBuffer)pVBuffer->Release();
    if(pIBuffer)pIBuffer->Release();
    if(swapchain)swapchain->Release();
    if(backbuffer)backbuffer->Release();
    if(dev)dev->Release();
    if(devcon)devcon->Release();
    if(pDStencil)pDStencil->Release();
    if(pDView)pDView->Release();
}


// this is the function that creates the shape to render
void InitGraphics()
{
    // create a triangle using the VERTEX struct
    VERTEX Vertices[] =
    {
        {-0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f, D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, D3DXCOLOR(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {0.75f, -0.5f, 0.0f, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
        {0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)},
    };

    DWORD Indices[]=
    {
        0,2,3,
        4,5,6,
    };

    // create the vertex buffer
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd,id;
    ZeroMemory(&bd, sizeof(bd));
    ZeroMemory(&id, sizeof(id));

    bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;                // write access access by CPU and GPU
    bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(VERTEX) * 7;             // size is the VERTEX struct * 4
    bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;       // use as a vertex buffer
    bd.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;    // allow CPU to write in buffer

    id.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;                // write access access by CPU and GPU
    id.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * 3*3;             // size is the DWORD struct * 2 * 3
    id.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;       // use as a index buffer
    id.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;    // allow CPU to write in buffer

    dev->CreateBuffer(&bd, NULL, &pVBuffer);       // create the buffer
    dev->CreateBuffer(&id, NULL, &pIBuffer);

    // copy the vertices into the buffer
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ms;
    devcon->Map(pVBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ms);    // map the buffer
    memcpy(ms.pData, Vertices, sizeof(Vertices));                       // copy the data
    devcon->Unmap(pVBuffer, NULL);                                      // unmap the buffer

     // copy the indices into the buffer
    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE ims;
    devcon->Map(pIBuffer, NULL, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, NULL, &ims);    // map the buffer
    memcpy(ims.pData, Indices, sizeof(Indices));                       // copy the data
    devcon->Unmap(pIBuffer, NULL);                                      // unmap the buffer
}


// this function loads and prepares the shaders
void InitPipeline()
{
    // load and compile the two shaders
    ID3D10Blob *VS, *PS;
    D3DX11CompileFromFile("shaders.hlsl", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
    D3DX11CompileFromFile("shaders.hlsl", 0, 0, "PShader", "ps_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);

    // encapsulate both shaders into shader objects
    dev->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pVS);
    dev->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pPS);

    // set the shader objects
    devcon->VSSetShader(pVS, 0, 0);
    devcon->PSSetShader(pPS, 0, 0);

    // create the input layout object
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ied[] =
    {
        {"POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
        {"COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0},
    };

    dev->CreateInputLayout(ied, 2, VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), &pLayout);
    devcon->IASetInputLayout(pLayout);
}
```

Debug tells me that the program fails on function CreateDepthStencilView and the reason being "First parameter is corrupted or null.".

Indeed, CreateTexture2D leaves my Texture2D COM object NULL, which is the cause of all the trouble.

**Can someone help me on why does this happen?**

Refer to InitD3D(). There lie the two functions mentioned above.

Comment: Almost all of the DirectX functions return an `HRESULT` that indicates any error. In your code, you don't seem to check anything, so first put some checks in to isolate the *first* call that fails.

Answer (score 2):

If you compile the application against the debug DirectX libraries you will get a more detailed error message when the Texture2D fails to create.  Probably one of the parameters is invalid.

[Capture DirectX 10/11 Debug Output to Visual Studio](http://blog.rthand.com/post/2010/10/25/Capture-DirectX-1011-debug-output-to-Visual-Studio.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I got it! Under the description of Depth Stencil View, Flags field had to be set.

```
descDSV.Flags = 0;            //0 for it 'not' being read only
```

Thanks for your time, guys!