# CreateDepthStencilView() is failing

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, shadow

I'm trying to create a shadow map in my DirectX application, but currently having trouble when creating the Depth Stencil view. CreateDepthStencilView() is leaving my ID3D11DepthStencilView* variable as NULL.

The only error I've managed to get from the HRESULT is `"The parameter is incorrect"`. It seems the problem is with both the D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC and the ID3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC as when I've replaced them with the depth texture and nullptr respectively, it works. I then replaced the working function parameters with the shadow map values one at a time and it did not work with either.

I have also tried setting `shadowDsv.Flags = 0` , as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042023/createtexture2d-and-createdepthstencilview-failing), but had the same result.

I'm following [this](https://takinginitiative.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/directx10-tutorial-10-shadow-mapping/) tutorial, the code is the same as his (except mine is DX11 not DX10), I'm unsure what the problem could be. This is my code:

Application.h

```cpp
    ID3D11Texture2D*        _shadowMapTexture;
    ID3D11DepthStencilView* _shadowMapStencil;
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* _shadowMapRV;
```

Application.cpp

```cpp
    //Set up shadow map
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC shadowTexDesc;
    shadowTexDesc.Width = _WindowWidth;
    shadowTexDesc.Height = _WindowHeight;
    shadowTexDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    shadowTexDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    shadowTexDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS;
    shadowTexDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    shadowTexDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    shadowTexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    shadowTexDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    shadowTexDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    shadowTexDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC shadowDsv;
    shadowDsv.Format = shadowTexDesc.Format;
    shadowDsv.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    shadowDsv.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shadowSrv;
    shadowSrv.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT;
    shadowSrv.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    shadowSrv.Texture2D.MipLevels = shadowTexDesc.MipLevels;
    shadowSrv.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;

    hr = _pd3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&shadowTexDesc, nullptr, &_shadowMapTexture);
    hr = _pd3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(_shadowMapTexture, &shadowDsv, &_shadowMapStencil);
    hr = _pd3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(_shadowMapTexture, &shadowSrv, &_shadowMapRV);
```

EDIT:
This is the console output when CreateDepthStencilView() is called. Thank you for the help so far.

```
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateDepthStencilView: The Format (0x27, R32_TYPELESS) is invalid, when creating a View; it is not a fully qualified Format castable from the Format of the Resource (0x27, R32_TYPELESS). [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #144: CREATEDEPTHSTENCILVIEW_INVALIDFORMAT]
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateDepthStencilView: The format (0x27, R32_TYPELESS) cannot be used with a DepthStencil view. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #144: CREATEDEPTHSTENCILVIEW_INVALIDFORMAT]
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateDepthStencilView: There were unrecognized flags specified in the DepthStencilView Flags field. The flags value was 0xcccccccc, while the valid flags are limited to 0x3. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #2097153: CREATEDEPTHSTENCILVIEW_INVALIDFLAGS]
Exception thrown at 0x76D235D2 in DX11 Framework.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x00B3EE98.
D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateDepthStencilView: Returning E_INVALIDARG, meaning invalid parameters were passed. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #148: CREATEDEPTHSTENCILVIEW_INVALIDARG_RETURN]
```

It seems the R32_TYPELESS format is what's causing the error. After looking at the documentation I see there are only a few allowable formats. Does anyone recommend a specific format for a shadow map? I've not done this before so unsure if any of the following would be a good subsitute:

```
DXGI_FORMAT_D16_UNORM
DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT
DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT
DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT_S8X24_UINT
DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN
```

Thanks again :)

Comment: Does the [debug layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/using-the-debug-layer-to-test-apps) produce any debug output?

Comment: Switch to debug D3D runtime, by setting `D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG` bit when creating the device. Then run your app with native debugger attached. Usually, debug runtime just prints what’s wrong with the way you’re trying to use D3D.

Comment: I think the format for sthe depth stencil view has to be a depth stencil format. DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT in your case

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Thank you for the suggestion it helped me diagnose the problem was with the Format. I've edited the post with the results.

Comment: Also thanks @Soonts for the same :)

Comment: @FelixBrüll
Thank you too, this was the problem and I will try now with the suggested format! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone else having this problem: my fix was to set the `D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC` format to `DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT`, and the `D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC` Flags equal to 0.

Comment: You should make a habit of zero-filling your structures so you don't have problem like this. ``D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC shadowDsv = {};`` is a simple way to zero-fill a structure with C++11 (VS 2013 or later). Alternatively, you can use the C++ helpers such as class ``CD3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC`` and use the parameter-based ctors. ``CD3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC shadowDsv(D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D, shadowTexDesc.Format);``